# past tense to report news in American English

Tags: past-tense, american-english, past-vs-present-perfect

I'd like to know whether the past tense can be used to report news in American English, as follows:

I'm writing to inform you that your brother **was promoted** to sales manager.

Is it necessary to use the present perfect form **has been promoted** here in AmE?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Present perfect is not necessary, simply better, if the promotion has only recently occurred and your letter is not referring to a promotion that happened in the (remote) past.

Comment: In AmE (as with any English really) in a letter, we would use the PP probably unless there is a specific time: "was promoted to sales manager last week". "You have been suggested as a good candidate to fill the vacancy".

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine.  As Tᴚoɯɐuo and Lambie mention, the present perfect helps set the time frame.  Present perfect is used for recent events, simple past for older events.

Examples:

> She **was** honored as the best student in her class.

With the simple past, without more context, we don't know when this happened.
  I could be talking about my great-great-grandmother, who was top of her class a hundred years ago.

> She **has been** honored as the best student in her class.

With the present perfect, we know this is a recent, completed event.

Similarly:

> They **were** here to repair the roof (last month, last year, ten years ago, etc.)
>
> They **have been** here to repair the roof (they just left)