# A tragic bus accident has happened

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

John's brother Peter lives in city X. He gets on a bus which later crashes into a dump truck. Shortly after the accident, he calls John and tells him that he's been severely injured. John gets upset because of that. A few moments later, John bumps into Rick on the street, and the following dialog takes place between them:

*Rick: "Why are you upset, John?"*

*John: "A tragic bus accident **has happened** in city X in which several people **have died**. My brother **was** on the bus. He **survived**, but he's in bad shape now."*

John first uses the present perfect to introduce the news to Rick, and then he switches to the simple past to expand on what has already been introduced. Are the bolded tenses used correctly in my example? Thanks.

Comment: The use of the PP is your choice. There is no right and wrong here. It depends on what **you want to say**. PP signals past tense but not when.

Comment: The tenses are fine, but John would probably say something like "There has been a dreadful bus accident in City X".

Comment: "My brother has been on the bus" would be wrong, because you need to express the temporal relationship between him being on the bus and the accident occurring, not between him being on the bus and now. You could use past tense or past continuous (e.g. *was riding on the bus*) (or even past perfect if he got off the bus before people died).

Comment: Present perfect is often used for reporting news, e.g. [see this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/151223/past-tense-to-report-news-in-american-english) [and this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/217319/have-been-found-vs-were-found). It's a convention in newspapers etc.